# Angular 5 Class extends class with extended injections

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular5, extends

I created such a class

```
@Injectable FooService {

    constructor(protected _bar:BarService){

    }
}
```

And extended it like this

```
@Injectable ExtFooService extends FooService {

    constructor(_bar:BarService){
        super(_bar);
    }
}
```

But then I extended BarService like this

```
@Injectable ExtBarService extends BarService {

   public myBarVar = "myBarVar";

    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

And now here

```
@Injectable ExtFooService extends FooService {

    constructor(_bar:ExtBarService){
        super(_bar);
    }

    someMethod(){
        return {
            key: this._bar.myBarVar
        };
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error:(51, 28) TS2551:Property 'myBarVar' does not exist on type 'BarService'.

It's like **ExtBarService** is forced to **BarService** because the super class wants that...
Is it possible that I have to do this?

```
@Injectable ExtFooService extends FooService {

    constructor(_bar:BarService, private _extBar: ExtBarService){
        super(_bar);
    }

    someMethod(){
        return {
            key: this._extBar.myBarVar
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Titian

Comment: Are you sure this is the error you are getting `Error:(51, 28) TS2551:Property 'myBarVar' does not exist on type 'BarService'.` on `key: _bar.myBarVar` ?  It should be `key: this._bar.myBarVar` and the error would be that the field is private ..

Comment: Yep, sorry the code it's like that...I transcribed it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override a `private` field, but you can't access the field from a derived class anyway, so I'm not sure where you get the error, but I'm guessing this is not your complete code.

The simplest solution would be to make the field `protected`. It would not be accessible from the outside, it would be accessible form derived classes, and you can override the type with a derived service without errors:

```
@Injectable class FooService {
    constructor(protected _bar:BarService){
    }
}

@Injectable class ExtFooService extends FooService {
    constructor(protected  _bar:ExtBarService){
        super(_bar);
    }

    someMethod(){
        return {
            key: this._bar.myBarVar
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I already did that...I set protected on super class injections...but same error..

Comment: I switched to protected, because when private, I got an error saying I couldn't access _bar since it was private...I'll fix the queston right away

Comment: You're a genius. Must be protected also in the extended class